# Python function receive a str and return table

Tags: python

***Input:*** "Uno dos tres cuatro cinco"

***Output:*** {"": ["Uno"], "Uno": ["dos"], "dos": ["tres"], "tres": ["cuatro"], "cuatro": ["cinco"]}

I created a function, that received 1 string argument. Function devide str to list and then to dict. First element in dictionary need to look like ***{"":null_index_in_the_string}***.

Function:

```
def mimic_dict(str):
    lst = str.split()
    prev = ""
    hash_table = {}

    for elem in lst:
        hash_table.setdefault(prev, []).append(elem)
        prev = elem

    return hash_table
```

Test:

```
def test():
    lst = ["Uno dos tres cuatro cinco", "Uno dos\tdos\nsinco", "a cat and a dog a fly"]
    check = ["{'': ['Uno'], 'Uno': ['dos'], 'dos': ['tres'], 'tres': ['cuatro'], 'cuatro': ['cinco']}", "{'': ['a'], 'a': ['cat', 'dog', 'fly'], 'cat': ['and'], 'and': ['a'], 'dog': ['a']}"]
    
    res_bool, res_check = [], list(map(mimic_dict, lst))
    res_check = list(map(str, res_check))
    
    for elem in check:
        if elem in res_check:
            res_bool.append(True)
    return res_bool
```

Comment: Why is this needed? I suspect an x/y problem

Comment: What should be the behaviour when a key is repeated?

Comment: You seem to have three test cases but only two checks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your function name is not very helpful**. Why is the function called
`mimic_dict()`? Perhaps the answer to that question is clear in the context of
your larger project. In any case, the reason is not evident to me, so I suggest
you put some effort into creating a better name. In the function's doc-string,
I attempt to describe the function's general behavior.

**When feasible, use specific names rather than generic names**. Your code uses
mostly generic names, such as `str`, `lst`, `elem`. But more specific names are
readily available: `text`, `words`, and `curr`. Notice in particular how much
better `curr` is than the bland `elem`. The latter tells us nearly nothing, but
`curr` emphasizes the contrast with `prev` and also ties into the function's
doc-string.

```python
def mimic_dict(text):
    '''
    Takes some text, splits it into words, and returns a dict
    where each previous word is the key for the current word (stored
    in a list to accommodate duplicates).
    '''
    words = text.split()
    prev = ''
    d = {}
    for curr in words:
        d.setdefault(prev, []).append(curr)
        prev = curr
    return d
```

**When testing, don't stringify expected data**. It's good that your question
includes some test code. However, your tests are a bit awkward because you
stringify the expected results. That's unnecessary. Just check for equality
against the expected dict.

**Unify test data, linking input to expected output**. As noted in a comment,
there was a mismatch between your number of test cases and expected outputs.
You can avoid such problems by unifying the test data from the outset, as shown
below.

```python
def test_mimic_dict():
    # Each test input is linked directly to expected output.
    checks = [
        (
            "Uno dos tres cuatro cinco",
            {'': ['Uno'], 'Uno': ['dos'], 'dos': ['tres'], 'tres': ['cuatro'], 'cuatro': ['cinco']},
        ),
        (
            "a cat and a dog a fly",
            {'': ['a'], 'a': ['cat', 'dog', 'fly'], 'cat': ['and'], 'and': ['a'], 'dog': ['a']},
        ),
        (
            "Uno dos\tdos\nsinco",
            {'': ['Uno'], 'Uno': ['dos'], 'dos': ['dos', 'sinco']},
        ),
    ]
    for inp, exp in checks:
        got = mimic_dict(inp)
        if got == exp:
            print('ok')
        else:
            print(got)
            print(exp)
```

**An alternative implementation using `itertools.pairwise`**. Your current
approach is fine, but here's a different way to do it. You could
also use a `collections.defaultdict` rather than `dict.setdefault`.

```python
from itertools import pairwise, chain

def mimic_dict(text):
    d = {}
    for prev, curr in pairwise(chain([''], text.split())):
        d.setdefault(prev, []).append(curr)
    return d
```